# File not found while running docker

Tags: linux, virtualization, docker

I am new to docker and need some help. I had a working docker image which I created using root file system archive by following these steps:-

```
1. cat file.tar.gz | docker import - docker_name
2. docker run --privileged -v /tmp:/tmp -v /dev/log:/dev/log -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup -h h1 --name h1 docker_name /sbin/init
```

Now I extracted the archive and added some files to it then re-archived it. Now I followed the same steps as above but this time I am getting a error:-
`docker run failed stats:/sbin/init` no such file or directory.

Am I doing anything wrong?? Please help

Comment: I don't think you can run init inside a container.

Comment: Can you list the contents of the tar before and after modifications? This sounds more like a broken tarball.